# Filtering Nested Objects with Lodash -- Getting Inconsistent Results

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to filter an array using Lodash. The problem is, within my main array, some of the array elements are objects and some are objects within arrays. I would like to use one filter that handles both scenarios. When I tried the code with var first, I only got incident number 270188929, but when I try the code with var second I only got incident number 370188929. Is it possible to write a filter with a nested object definition that will handle both? Or do I need a function? Is so, what function would work?

Here is my code:

```
var array = [{
"category": "test",
"incidentInformation": {
    "incidentNumber": "270188929",
},
"numberInformation": {
    "number": "1",
    "type": "moderate",
},
}, {
"category": "test2",
"incidentInformation": {
    "incidentNumber": "370188929",
},
"numberInformation": [{
    "number": "1",
    "type": "moderate",
}, {
    "number": "1",
    "type": "moderate",
}]
}];

var first = _.filter(array, {
numberInformation: {
    type: "moderate"
}
});

var second = _.filter(array, {
numberInformation: [{
    type: "moderate"
}]
});
```

Comment: Kindly mark the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not encapsulate what it is to be moderate in a predicate:

```
var isModerate = function(item){
    return item.numberInformation.type == 'moderate' || 
           _.some(item.numberInformation, {type: 'moderate'});
}
```

And then use that in a filter (or wherever else you may need it):

```
var result = _.filter(array, isModerate);
```

To make it more generic you could create a function that returns a predicate for you:

```
var isOfType = function(type) {

    return function(item){
        return item.numberInformation.type == type || 
               _.some(item.numberInformation, {type: type});
    }
}

var result = _.filter(array, isOfType('moderate'));
```

Comment: I think you meant to use == instead of = in both return statements. In this example both return statements (with = and with ==) worked, but when I tried it in my full application, the = changed the data. I chose this as the best answer because once I changed the = to == it worked. Also I thought this answer was more simple. And I appreciate the generic function.

Comment: I hang my head in shame :). School boy error. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine the two criteria into a single filter, I would recommend `cond()`:

```
_.filter(array, _.cond([
  [v => v.numberInformation.type === 'moderate', _.stubTrue],
  [v => _.some(v.numberInformation, { type: 'moderate' }), _.stubTrue]]
));
```

The pairs passed to `cond()` are the *condition* function, followed by the *value* function. The idea is that conditions will keep evaluating items until one returns true, or until they run out. When something is found, a `true` value is returned to filter.

With this approach, it's easier to maintain logic because it's declarative.

Comment: This answer worked. I did not choose it because I liked Gruff Bunny's answer, which I felt was easier to understand and provided a generic function that could be used in other circumstances. Can you explain what the benefits of the _.cond() method are?

Answer (score 0):

```
   var first= _.filter(array, function(o) { 
        return o.numberInformation.type == 'moderate'; 
     });



    var second = _.filter(array, function (o) {
      return _.some(o.numberInformation, { 'type': 'moderate' });
    });
```

Comment: Altough this answer worked, it does not use one filter to handle both the array elements that are objects and the array elements that are objects within arrays. This answer does help explain why my code was not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any library to filter a list of objects. You can simply use `filter()` method

```
var matchingItems = array.filter(function(item) { 
    return item.numberInformation.type == 'moderate'; 
 });
```

Comment: This answer did not work. It only gave back the first incident number.